# Angular - map is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to filer an Observable in my angular project, but it says: "... .map is not a function" so, can you explain what's wrong with my code?

**tasks.component.ts** *(map also imported from rxjs/operators)*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tasks = this.tasksService.tasks.map(x => x.filter(y => y.isDone == this.completed));
    this.tasksService.getTasks();
  }
```

And here's my service which provides the Observable:

**task.service.ts**

```
export class TasksService {
  private _tasks = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);
  tasks = this._tasks.asObservable();
  constructor(private http : Http) {
    console.log('Tasks Service is initialized...');
  }

  getTasks() {
    this.http.get(URL).subscribe(x => {
      this._tasks.next(x.json());
    });
  }
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs/angular u r using

Comment: what is the version of RXJS ?

Comment: 5.5.10 is the version of my rxjs. I've just checked it.

Comment: Why are you using `HttpModule` it is deprecated you should use `HttpClientModule`

Comment: @Vikas where has the OP mentioned about using `HttpModule`? you are just assuming I guess ...

Comment: @Faisal  `constructor(private http : Http)` is not it quite evident from this that OP is using `HttpModule`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `map` like this if you are using `rxjs` version less than 6.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

---

If you are using `rxjs` version 6 or greater, then firstly you have to import operator like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Secondly, you have to use `pipe` before `map`:

```
this.tasks = this.tasksService.tasks.pipe(
                 map(x => x.filter(y => y.isDone == this.completed))
             );
```

Comment: I'm using `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` right now. That's not the same?

Comment: ^ this is version 6+ way of importing

Comment: It works well with `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` at me with rxjs version 5.5.10... By the way the problem was I didn't call map inside the pipe function. Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Observable.subscribe directly should work.like below

@Injectable()
export class HallService {
    public http:Http;
    public static PATH:string = 'app/backend/'    

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http=http;
    }

    getHalls() {
    // ########### No map
           return this.http.get(HallService.PATH + 'hall.json');
    }
}


export class HallListComponent implements OnInit {
    public halls:Hall[];
    / *** /
    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getHalls()
           .subscribe(halls => this.halls = halls.json()); // <<--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too, when using somearray.map(...), and the problem turned out to be that somearray was null cause it had not been imported from the backend properly.